# different from, or opposite to my traditional statements. Vs. different from, or opposite to, my traditional statements

Tags: meaning-in-context, punctuation, commas

> - I adapted to the innovative ideas that are different from, or opposite to, my traditional statements.
> - I adapted to the innovative ideas that are different from, or opposite to my traditional statements.

- the difference between two these sentences is: i took "the comma" out of the **second** sentence, so what is the difference in meaning between them?

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is wrong with that comma after "**to**". Actually, you have two good options here:

1. I adapted to the innovative ideas that are different from or opposite to my traditional statements. (*No comma at all*)
2. I adapted to the innovative ideas that are different from, or opposite to my traditional statements. (*A comma after "**from**" only*)

Reference - [*Google Books Search for "**different from, or opposite to**"*](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22different%20from,%20or%20opposite%20to%22&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=bks&biw=1536&bih=779)

The only solution to use a comma after "**to**", which I know of, is if "*different from, or opposite to*" starts a sentences:

- Whether different from, or opposite to, his ideas will not be the same as yours. (Which can be rewritten as "*His ideas will be different from, or opposite to yours, but not the same.*")

Comment: See this example: "You use otherwise to refer in a general way to actions or situations that are very different from, or the opposite ***to*** , your main statement" taken from https://www.google.jo/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/otherwise

Comment: @BavyanYaldo I bet that if you send them (*Collins dictionary*) this sentence they will remove the comma after "**to**" since it's really incorrect.

Comment: There are plenty of people who would put a comma after **to**. Punctuation conventions vary.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo would the meaning change whether we put a comma or not?

Comment: No, the meaning would not change.

Comment: I would favour using both commas.  I dislike the version with only one comma.  So I would disagree with SovereignSun and agree with Bavyan Yaldo.  Also, the Google Books search which SovereignSun cites as a reference contains plenty of examples that use both commas.  No evidence has been presented that this is incorrect.

Comment: I would use the comma after "to" because of rule 3 [here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/607/), which states: "Use a pair of commas in the middle of a sentence to set off clauses, phrases, and words that are not essential to the meaning of the sentence. Use one comma before to indicate the beginning of the pause and one at the end ..." Since the phase "or opposite to" can be stripped out without affecting the syntax or semantics, the comma at the end is needed. Although, I dislike associating pauses with commas, in this case, the second comma helps with pacing as well.